# Angular decorator don't works on this scope

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

With a custom decorator I want inject into a method a property with another method inside. The decorator:

```
function test() {
  return function(target, key, descriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, "foo", {
        value: () => console.log("foo fired!"),
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false
      });
      return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

usage:

```
import { Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `<button (click)="bar()">Test</button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {

  @test()
  bar() {
    console.log("bar fired!");

    const self = this;
    (self as any).foo(); // this works!

    (this.bar as any).foo(); // this doesn't works!
  }
}
```

see online https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhfasr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I don't understand because this works:

```
@test()
bar() {
    const self = this;
    (self as any).foo();
}
```

but this doesn't works (Error: this.bar.foo is not a function):

```
@test()
bar() {
    (this.bar as any).foo(); // Error: this.bar.foo is not a function
}
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside of `bar` function when you call it `this` keyword references to AppComponent instance. it is expected that you added `foo` element to AppComponent when you call `bar` method.

if you still want to access it like `(this.bar as any).foo();` then define foo field on a `bar`, not `this`

```
function test() {
  return function(target, key, descriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value; // no point of overriding it. we just add a field
    Object.defineProperty(originalMethod, "foo", {
      value: () => console.log("foo fired!"),
      enumerable: false,
      writable: false
    });
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```